Matplotlib multiple graph resizing issue in a tkinter frame
I am trying to set up a program that contains matplotlib graph in a tkinter frame but even if I tried subframes, different pack and grid methods, It didn't work. figsize() doesn't work either. (4, 4) is too big and (3, 3) doesn't entirely show the graph. What I need to do in order to align 4 graphs in a frame?
The app:
aaaa = {
    0:0,
    5:5,
    10:10,
    15:15,
}

bbbb = {
    0:0,
    5:5,
    16:13,
    20:27,
}

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3.5, 4))
ax1.plot(list(aaaa.keys()), list(aaaa.values()))

ax1.set_title("Roket İrtifa")
ax1.set_ylabel("metre")
ax1.set_xlabel("Zaman / saniye")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3.5, 4))
ax2.plot(list(bbbb.keys()), list(bbbb.values()))
ax2.set_title("İrtifa")
ax2.set_ylabel("metre")
ax2.set_xlabel("Zaman / saniye")
app = CTk()
app.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

right_frame = CTkFrame(master=app, width=670, height=610)
right_frame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nsew", rowspan=2, padx=(0, 20))
right_frame.grid_propagate(False)
upper_frame = CTkFrame(master=right_frame, width=669, height=305)
upper_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ew")
upper_frame.grid_propagate(False)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=upper_frame)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=upper_frame)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)


lower_frame = CTkFrame(master=right_frame, width=669, height=305)
lower_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ew")
lower_frame.grid_propagate(False)

canvas3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=lower_frame)
canvas3.draw()
canvas3.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

canvas4 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=lower_frame)
canvas4.draw()
canvas4.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

app.mainloop()

This is the result I'm getting (screenshot from the original app, this is just another window but the same issue):
Program Image
Thanks.

It is better to provide a [mre] as currently the posted code cannot be executed.

Now I edited it so you can execute it. @acw1668
